# Understanding of C pointers, incrementing and dereferencing

Tags: c

I am given a program and am supposed to predict its output.

I have tried to understand the program step by step and write down the value of the variables at each point in the program, but I am not sure what these operations do:

`increment(&i); 
increment(&a[i]);`

```
#include<stdio.h> 

void increment(int *ptr){
    ++ *ptr;
} 

int main(){ 
    int a[]={5,10},i=0; 
    increment(a); 
    increment(&i); 
    increment(&a[i]); 
    increment(a+i);
    printf("\nResult:i=%d\n",i); 
    printf("a[0]=%d\n a[1]= %d\n", a[0], a[1]);
    return 0 ;
}
```

The solution is:

```
Result: i = 1 
a[0] = 6
a[1] = 12
```

Could you help me understand how I can derive the solution?
Thank you!

Comment: Which exact step are you unsure about? Do you understand what the addressof operator `&` does?

Comment: `++ *ptr;` is the same as `*ptr += 1;`

Comment: `&a[i]` is the same as `a + i` is to the value the same as `a`.

Comment: Thank you for all your explanations! One thing I am still unsure about is what happens after `increment(a)`. I thought his would increment a so that it points to a[1], but apparently this is not the case?

Comment: @user8558648 the function `increment()` takes a pointer and increments the pointed value. `increment(a)` increments the value stored at `a[0]`. Check my answer for step-by-step explanation

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with some background information.

First, the expression `++i` evaluates to the current value of `i` plus 1 - as a *side effect*, the value stored in `i` is incremented.  As a standalone expression, it's roughly equivalent to `i = i + 1`.

Secondly, except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" (`T [N]`) will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" (`T *`), and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

Finally, the expression `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)` - given a starting address `a`, offset `i` *elements* (not bytes!) from that address and dereference the result.  This means that the expression `a + i` is equivalent to the expression `&a[i]`.

Let's see how this applies to your code:

In the `increment` function, the line

```
++ *ptr;
```

adds 1 to the thing that `ptr` points to.

When you call `increment(a)`, the *expression* `a` has type "2-element array of `int`".  Since `a` is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, this expression "decays" to type "pointer to `int`" (`int *`), and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of `a`.  IOW, it's exactly the same as if you had written `increment(&a[0])`.  Therefore, in the `increment` function, the following are true:

```
 ptr == &a[0]
*ptr ==  a[0]
```

Thus, the expression `++ *ptr` is equivalent to the expression `++ a[0]`.  After this call, `a[0]` is now 6.

When you call `increment(&i)`, `ptr` now points to `i`:

```
 ptr == &i
*ptr ==  i
```

so `++ *ptr` is equivalent to the expression `++ i`, so you're adding 1 to `i`.

When you call `increment(a[i])`, `i` is equal to 1, so this is equivalent to calling `increment(a[1])`.  After this call, `a[1]` is equal to 11.

And finally, `increment(a+i)` is equivalent to `increment(&a[i])`, which is equivalent to `increment(&a[1])`, and after this call `a[1]` is equal to  12.

Answer (score 0):

> but I am not sure what these operations do:

`increment(&i);` passes the address of `i` variable to your increment function. That function dereferences the pointer and increments the pointed-to value, which is essentially equivalent to `i++`.

`increment(&a[i])` does the same, but now it passes the address of the *i*-th element of `a`. Since `i` was incremented to `1` before, it is equivalent to `a[1]++`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `increment(int *ptr)` expects a pointer to an `int`, i.e. an address.

Since the variable `i` is of type `int` you have to pass its address by using the *address-of* operator `&` as in: `increment(&i)`

`a[i]` is equal to `*(a+i)` - i.e. you access the address of the array element at `a+i` and dereference it in order to get the value of that array element at position `i`.
Same reason as in the first case, `increment` expects a pointer and therefore you have to pass an address as in: `increment(&a[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's a step by step explanation in inline comments. Hope it helps. You may need to scroll horizontally to read the full comment.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
// This function takes a pointer to int and increments the pointed value
void increment(int *ptr){++ *ptr;}      

int main(){ 
    int a[]={5,10},i=0; // It doesn't look so but here, a is a pointer to int
    increment(a);       // increments the first value pointed by a (a[0]) so now a is [6,10]
    increment(&i);      // increments i, now i = 1
    increment(&a[i]);   // increments a[1], now a = [6,11]
    increment(a+i);     // since i = 1, increments the value right after the one pointed by a so again, a[1], now a = [6,12]
    printf("\nResult:i=%d\n",i);        
    printf("a[0]=%d\n" "a[1]= %d\n");
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: _It doesn't look so but here, `a` is a pointer to int_. No, `a` is not pointer. `a` is an array of integer. Array is not pointer. Array and pointer are different.

Comment: Yes @H.S, Arrays declared like this `int a[]` have a *slightly* different behaviour than pointers since they are statically allocated but in fact, they are really pointers in the sense that the value that `a` holds is an address in memory. And `a[0]` is equivalent to `*a`. Check this snippet : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/SGCJ1z

Comment: @ Ki Jéy _a[0] is equivalent to *a_ doesn't mean that array `a` is a pointer.

Comment: the variable `a` contains an address. You can read the value stored in that address by dereferencing it with `*`. `*a` contains the integer you want. Call it whatever you want. For me it's a pointer.